# table Betti numbers for real Grassmannians

Tags: homology-cohomology, grassmannian, betti-numbers

I am looking for a table of Betti numbers for real oriented and not oriented  Grassmannians. Is there some references to get this ?

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.at/books?id=P08bCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=table+of+Betti+numbers+for+real+Grassmannians&source=bl&ots=RKUEAN3UA5&sig=hQO8Lc47TLj8pKVm7NFAJqLKRos&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIorCxqP7aAhVDzqQKHak0A9kQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=table%20of%20Betti%20numbers%20for%20real%20Grassmannians&f=false) is a result, from a table.

Comment: @DietrichBurde excellent this is exactly the paper I am reading. Do you know where I can get some table ?

Comment: I guess, the author uses "table" in another sense. He wants to say: "Looking at a few examples, we can easily see that the Betti numbers only depends on $p$ even or $p$ odd". So there is no "table", I guess, or the table is the result.